# Is it possible to implement SSL/HTTPS on a SharePoint site thats not running on port 80?

Tags: iis, ssl

I'm finding this concept a rather confusing perhaps or may be this is a very basic question.

I have a sharepoint web application running on port 90 and have got a SSL certificate.

Lets say : `http://mydomain.com:90/`

In IIS, once I install and configure the certificate , I'm assuming the IIS bindings for the mydomain website will look something like this

```
http*   mydomain.com    90 <br>
https*  mydomain.com    443
```

So basically, my question is when users type 
`https://mydomain.com without putting :90/` will this work ?

Answer (score 3):

No, this will not work if you only do that.

If you make all of the configuration changes in IIS (on all of the WFE servers) to add the new binding to the IIS site, but without telling SharePoint about it then you'll get a SharePoint monster which sometimes will kind of work. Depending on how you navigate to the first page it'll show that using the https protocol or redirect you to the http version (You can try `https://mydomain.com/pages/default.aspx` and `https://mydomain.com`), but any internal links will always be to the http version.

You should extend your web application and let SharePoint create the binding on a new IIS site (you still have to add/configure the certificate on all servers).

One example can be found her: [Extending a Sharepoint Web Application To Enable SSL](http://notuserfriendly.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/extending-a-sharepoint-web-application-to-enable-ssl/)

Comment: +1 - Extending the web app is key for adding SSL to an already existing SharePoint Web App

Comment: Without extending I tried , to my surprise It worked just fine. However I'm still giving another to the article shared by Per.

Comment: Is extending the web application the only way of making the site available via SSL?